# How to positioning every child in flex/grid/whatever simultaneously with nth-child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I have this code:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.child,
.child:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child:last-child:nth-child(1) {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.child:nth-child(1),
.child:last-child:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.child:nth-last-child(4) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
Test with 1 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
</div>
Test with 2 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
</div>
Test with 3 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
</div>
Test with 4 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:orange;">4</div>
</div>
```

But I wish the last example had a different order, that is:

```
1 2
3 4
```

The important thing is that I cannot add different classes for each of the flex children.
The Twitter gallery behaves similarly, but it's more complicated there (it's flex in flex and probably some JS, although it probably works differently).
I need all the above-mentioned cases to work simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using grid instead of flex. Take a look at this:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

/* in case there is only one child */
.child:first-child:nth-last-child(1){
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

/* in case there are 2 children */
.child:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.child:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .child{
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

/* in case there are 3 children, make the first one span 2 rows */
.child:first-child:nth-last-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
Test with 1 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
</div>
Test with 2 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
</div>
Test with 3 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
</div>
Test with 4 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:orange;">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I meant. I was to add that if you can't flex, it can also be grid or other

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you need to structure your flex grid like this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
Test with 4 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:orange;">4</div>
</div>
```

Note that instead of using `flex-direction: column` we use `flex-wrap: wrap` to push the elements to the next row.

Comment: If it were that simple, I wouldn't ask for help ;) I need all the above-mentioned cases to work simultaneously